# Magento 2 Catalog Product Flat Data not reindexing

Tags: magento2, reindex

the indexing of magento product Flat data is staying on "index required".The mode is on "Scheme" and the cron is running. I tried several things like:

> truncate catalog_product_flat_1, catalog_product_flat_2,
>   catalog_product_flat_3, catalog_product_flat_4

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento indexer:reset 
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento indexer:reset catalog_product_flat
```

**Error :-**

> **message in shell: State for the same indexer already exists.**

`update indexer_state set status = 'invalid' where status != 'valid';`

Then reindex again

**Can anybody help?
Thanks**

Answer (score 1):

**In Database Run This Query**

```
update indexer_state set status = 'invalid' where indexer_id = 'catalog_product_flat';
```

**And After This run indexer:reindex command**

Comment: did this, but i see still the same error.

Comment: bin/magento indexer:status and check catalog_product_flat status

Comment: result: Product Flat Data:                                 Reindex required

Comment: try to indexer:reindex

Comment: I already did multiple times, without a result

Comment: php bin/magento indexer:reset catalog_product_flat and after this try indexer:reindex

Comment: Did, no results

Answer (score 0):

In  your database, try running the below commnand

`update indexer_state set status = 'invalid' where status != 'valid';`

Then reindex again

Comment: Hi, did but still same error: State for the same indexer already exists.

Comment: try running command with sudo

Comment: What's the right commando with sudo?

Comment: sudo php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: same error still showing

Comment: Run this in database and try again
"update indexer_state set status = 'invalid' where indexer_id = 'catalog_product_flat';"

Comment: Result of: php bin/magento indexer:reset catalog_product_flat
State for the same indexer already exists.

Comment: May be there is a issue of user privilages , check out this link grant privilages and then try reindexing. "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11946012/how-to-add-super-privileges-to-mysql-database"

Comment: I don't think because it's updating the db after trying queries.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by duplicate indexer state rows in `indexer_state` table of your database.

Run this query to see, which indices contain multiple state rows in this table:

```
SELECT * FROM `indexer_state`;
```

Identify indices with duplicate state rows and delete excess state rows by running this query:

```
DELETE FROM `indexer_state` WHERE `state_id` IN (500,501,502);
```

Provide all `state_id` values that have `indexer_id` values that repeat more than once, excluding the original `state_id` values.

After running this query there will be no duplicate indexer states and the index should no longer throw that error.